# Why does GPGME / GnuPG use pinentry for password input?

Tags: c++, gnupg, openpgp, gpgme

GPGME uses a `passphrase_cb` method to fetch the password from the user for operations, which require access to private keys. This callback can only be overwritten for symmetric encryption, in all other cases the default pinentry is used.

All this effort seems to be pretty uncomfortable, especially because GPGME is an API which shall be used for programming C/C++/... applications. It might be easier (for a programmer who would like to use GPGME) in some cases if the passphrase could be passed to encrypt/sign functions directly. I also saw that other implementations of OpenPGP (to be more precise NetPGP) use a callback.

So I wonder if there is any security specific reason to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG starting with 2.1 removed the most critical private key functionality into the `gpg-agent`, to reduce the attack surface on the most intimate secrets -- the private keys.

Such a callback would not only expose the passphrase to the application you're writing (which probably means an even larger attack surface than GnuPG would be), but also GnuPG gets aware of the passphrase.

If you really need to control entry of the passphrase from your application, you have several choices.

### Implementing Pinentry

The information flow would then be: your application calls GnuPG through GPGME, GnuPG requests some private key operation from `gpg-agent`, which again asks your application for the passphrase. Be aware this will only work if you also started the `gpg-agent` with appropriate pinentry configuration (you might have to start another instance, separate from the one already running on your system).

### `gpg-preset-passphrase`

The most important use case of passing the passphrase directly is in headless daemons, where no humans waits for entering the passphrase. GnuPG also brings a small utility `gpg-preset-passphrase` (on Debian and derivatives, it is installed as `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase`), which also can be used to precache the passphrase (so it is not queried for a configurable time).

### Pinentry Loopback

With GnuPG 2.1, another option was added: in `gpg-agent`, you can allow pinentry loopback with the `allow-loopback-pinentry` option. An additional parameter `pinentry-mode` set to `loopback` in GnuPG/GPGME should allow you to handle passphrase interaction using `passphrase_cb` again.

But: consider this exposes the passphrase not both your application and GnuPG, and might prove to be a (possibly minor but existing and maybe unnecessary) security risk. Also, GnuPG 2.1 is not yet widely spread, which might be a problem if you do not control the environment.

Comment: How would that pinentry loopback work technically? I can see that GPGME seems to have `gpgme_set_pinentry_mode` (in the ruby version, but I didn't found it in the [original documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/)). Also I dont have direct access to GnuPG (just trough GPGME) currently. How would I set the `allow-loopback` option there?

Comment: `allow-loopback` is an option in `gpg-agent` and cannot be set through GPGME. It can also not be set by calling GnuPG. You have to edit the `gpg-agent` configuration for this, to tell the agent to allow reduced passphrase security.